# Slow query with odbc driver

Tags: c#, oracle, odbc, oledb, .net-framework-version

I have a table with 1,000,000 record.

```
create table CCM.SPVACTION_STOPPER
(
  revision                    NUMBER default 0 not null,
  heat_id                     VARCHAR2(16) default ' ' not null,
  strand_num                  NUMBER default 0 not null,
  stopper_position            NUMBER default 0 not null,
  speed_value                 NUMBER default 0,
  mould_level                 NUMBER default 0,
  ladel_net_steel_wgt         NUMBER default 0,
  tundish_net_steel_wgt       NUMBER default 0,
  ladel_calculation_steel_wgt NUMBER default 0,
  casting_lenght              NUMBER default 0
)
tablespace USERS
  pctfree 10
  initrans 1
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 64K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
-- Create/Recreate indexes 
create index CCM.IND2_SPVSTOPP on CCM.SPVACTION_STOPPER (HEAT_ID)
  tablespace USERS
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 64K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
create index CCM.IND3_SPVSTOPP on CCM.SPVACTION_STOPPER (REVISION)
  tablespace USERS
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 64K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
create index CCM.IND_SPVSTOPP on CCM.SPVACTION_STOPPER (HEAT_ID, REVISION)
  tablespace USERS
  pctfree 10
  initrans 2
  maxtrans 255
  storage
  (
    initial 64K
    next 1M
    minextents 1
    maxextents unlimited
  );
```

When i run this query with ODBC

```
select * from ccm.spvaction_stopper 
where heat_id = :heatID and rownum<10
```

In line `Command.ExecuteReader()` say error

```
{"ERROR [HYT00] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation\n"}
```

But when run this query with OLEDB driver or run int PLSQl, run in less than 1 second.

Please help me to fast run this query with ODBC.

(I use .net framework4)

Comment: I think you will probably need to post your C# code

Answer (score 0):

I add `QTO=F` to connection string for prevent

`ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation`

error

`QTO=F` use to disable query timeout.